# error when sync Gradle project in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization

I can not sync my `gradle` project. Every time I sync, it shows an error:

`Error:(11) Tag <style> can not appear inside <style>, only <item>`

When I edit `value.xml` & `value-v21.xml` or remove `<style>` , it will reappear.

How to solve the problem?

**build gradle app:**

```
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ir.bijac.com.bijac"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

**And dependencies:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

[image: Description image]

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the *value-v21.xml* and if  tag is still nested in *value.xml* , edit it.
Hope this helps

Comment: I deleted it, but it was rebuilt

Answer (score 0):

Put MyCheckbox style to outside of AppTheme.NoActionBar

Comment: When I edit `value.xml` & `value-v21.xml` or remove `<style>` , it will reappear.

Comment: Is there any other value-*.xml file? Did you try Clean Project - Rebuild Project? Search for "MyCheckbox" in project to find if anywhere left nested style such as <style><style> *** </style></style>

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `MyCheckBox` style from inside of `AppTheme.NoActionBar` style.

> Tag `<style>` can not appear inside `<style>`, only `<item>`

It's says that a `style` can not contain another `style` inside, just an `item`, so removing `MyCheckBox` style outside it should work.

Make sure your `layout.xml` only contains one `style` inside a component, for instance :

```
<Checkbox>
...
...
style=@style/MyCheckBox
</Checkbox>
```

Oh, I see you can edit so, please try first :

```
File/Invalidate Caches/Restart
```

if it does not work, make sure you can scroll up and down in your styles, then you can edit it.

Also make sure you are not editing the files that Android studio are generating automatically make sure you are editing this :

```
app->src->main->res->values
```

Comment: When I edit `value.xml` & `value-v21.xml` or remove `<style>` , it will reappear.

Comment: One of the errors was fixed by resetting the cache. Now you're just `value-v21.xml`
The file branch is here:

`app / build / intermediates / res / merged / debug / value-v21 / value-v21.xml`

Comment: remove it @HasanAbbasi

Comment: I deleted it, but it was rebuilt

Comment: Can you upload the source code to github or something so I can take a look?

Comment: Yes, I can, but which part of the source? The project has an enormous number of pages

Comment: Try to upload everything so I can check what's wrong

Comment: I'm sorry, since this project is not personal and made for a start-up company, I can not get the source code of the project.

Comment: I can not help then, if you have teamviewer I can try to help you

Comment: Yes, I have a TeamViewer. Where to start?

Comment: Do you have the id and password

Comment: The problem with your help was solved.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok, then mark this answer as a correct one if you want :)

Comment: I deleted all Mycheckbox tags in Style.xml

Comment: Yes. Worked!
Until I updated Android Studio to version 3.3.0, I came across a lot of problems.
Can you help me with TeamViewer?

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear you can't do this

`<stle><style> </style></style>`

instead what you can do is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#F00</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I can't edit `value.xml` & `value-v21.xml` or remove `<style>` , it will reappear.

Comment: definetly you will not be able to edit yellowed files go to your res/values/style/values files and edit it.

Comment: Explain the solution further